# Rotation around center point with velocity - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, rotation, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi fellow programmers!

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have an image placed in the center of the screen. When I put my finger on this image, and rotate my finger, the image should rotate as well. When i release the finger, i would like the image to decelerate for x period of time. (Let's say that it should decelerate slowly). Basically I'm trying to develop a Spin-the-bottle application, but I can't figure out the velocity part.

**What I've tried:**

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468559/rotate-image-on-center-using-one-finger-touch) to get the one finger rotation, and it works great so far, but it doesn't include the velocity part. And honestly, I have no idea, how to calculate the velocity.

**What I'm asking of you:**

A "simple" way of doing one-finger-rotation with velocity, of an UIImageView in a normal UIViewController. (Or just using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468559/rotate-image-on-center-using-one-finger-touch) method to the rotation part, and somehow implement velocity.) Examples are appreciated!

If you have any questions, please comment!

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Ever get a good working solution for this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. :(

Comment: I found this: http://rdsquared.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/circular-scrolling-inertia/ Possibly could help you?